# History in query

Tags: soql, field-history

I am trying to get a list of reasons why clients were lost (absagegrund) this week. How would I go about this?

```
Select o.Absagegrund1__c, (Select StageName, createddate From Histories) 
From Opportunity o﻿ where stagename = 'Geschlossen und verloren' 
and createddate = this_week group by o.Absagegrund1__c
```

Thanks

Comment: 'Select Absagegrund1__c, StageName (Select NewValue From Histories) From Opportunity where StageName.NewValue = 'Geschlossen und verloren' and createddate = this_week group by Absagegrund1__c'

I have this now, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the group by clause. The query below should work

```
Select Absagegrund1__c, (Select StageName, createddate From Histories) 
        From Opportunity where stagename = 'Geschlossen und verloren'
        AND createddate = this_week
```

Comment: It still gives me an error. But I have found a way around it. Once it is closed it is usually not modified anymore, so I just take the ones from opportunity where StageName = lost and closed and last modified = this week.

But thank you!